# Getting IP from triggered client in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ip

I am using Jenkins for executing some shell scripts remotely. So I have a job, which could be triggered by URL, i.e. http://testserver.de:8009/job/receiveCSR/build?token=123.
Now I need the IP from the host, which sent the HTTP-Request. How can I use this in my shell-script? When I look at one special build, I can see "Started from external client 10.1.2.44" (only a translation from my German Jenkins, original: "Gestartet durch entfernten Rechner 10.1.2.44".

Does anyone know how to include this information in the shell script inside the job?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround you may try. You can create a post-project and execute it after the current-project is done, in the post-project you can parse the log or job configuration xml file to find the ip address of the remote trigger host. hope that helps.